# Adjusting exact height of the table rows

Tags: tables, color, height

I am trying to adjust exact height of the row in my table, but the output is not good:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\newcolumntype{O}{>{\columncolor{mColor1}}}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\caption{Summary}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| OD{2.2cm} | E{1.1cm} | E{3cm} | E{3cm} | @{}m{0pt}@{} | }
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type & \\  [0.6cm]
\hline
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type & \\ [0.6cm]
\hline
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type & \\ [0.6cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output table is like this which has some issues at the right side of the table including overlap of the color and also one extra vertical line:

[image]

How can I solve the issues?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use

```
@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][0pt]}m{0pt}@{}
```

instead of

```
@{}m{0pt}@{} |
```

so the hidden column is not considered when coloring the row.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\newcolumntype{O}{>{\columncolor{mColor1}}}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][0pt]}m{0pt}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\caption{Summary}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| OD{2.2cm} | E{1.1cm} | E{3cm} | E{3cm} | N }
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type &\\[0.6cm]
\hline
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type &\\[0.6cm]
\hline
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type &\\[0.6cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. could you please also show me how I can define a new command for @{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt][0pt]}m{0pt}@{} so that I don't need to include it all long in the table?

Comment: @NESHOM Of course. See the edited answer. I've called it `N`.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the height of cells in columns of a type prefixed with the letter `S`, if you  use the `cellspace` package. You don't have to use an empty column either, but should load the `caption` package to have a correct vertical spacing between caption and table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = footnotesize}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\newcolumntype{O}{>{\columncolor{mColor1}}}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{8pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{8pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\caption{Summary}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| OD{2.2cm} | E{1.1cm} | S{E{3cm}} | E{3cm} | }
\hline
\rowcolor{mColor1}
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type \tabularnewline
\hline
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type \\
\hline
Author(s) & App. & Algorithm / Technique & Camera Type \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It, I think, can not adjust height of the rows individually. Also it is more complicated and need more package compared to karlkoeller's answer. So if you don't mind I am going to mark his as the answer. Thank you very much again, I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually the difference with karlkoeller's answer is loading `cellspace` instead of `array` (which is useful for a lot of other things). It adjusts row heights individually in this very sense; it ensures a minimal vertical white space at the top and the bottom of cells; the rest of the cell has its natural height. On another hand, the caption package should be used even with his solution: basic latex forgets to swap the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` when the caption is put *above* the table.